# How to make Dropdown button that changes its title have different links?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui

So far I've managed to get bootstrap dropdown button to change its title depending on the clicked item.

[image]

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjagZR)

But besides that I want every dropdown item to have its own link when clicking on them.

How can I do this?

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <div ng-controller='DropdownCtrl'>

    <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
      <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
        {{button}} <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="uib-dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
        <li role="menuitem">
          <a href="#" ng-click="change(action)" ng-repeat="action in actions">{{action}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']).controller('DropdownCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.button = "Button dropdown";
  $scope.actions = [
    "Action", "Another Action", "Something else here"
  ];

  $scope.change = function(name){
    $scope.button = name;
  }
});
```

Comment: use [ng-href](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

Comment: @giorgio Could you provide a little example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this, using [`ng-href`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref)

First change the button to an anchor and add the ng-href attribute;

```
<a href ng-href="{{ href }}" id="single-button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
    {{ name }} <span class="caret"></span>
</a>
```

Then alter the actions variable to hold an array of objects:

```
$scope.actions = [
    {
        name: 'Action',
        href: 'action.html'
    },
    {
        name: 'Another Action',
        href: 'another_action.html'
    },
    {
        name: 'Something else here',
        href: 'something_else_here.html'
    }
];
```

Then finally alter the change function to update the name of the action *and* the href

```
$scope.change = function(action){
    $scope.name = action.name;
    $scope.href = action.href;
}
```

**EDIT** Now with a [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OyQvLj). Note that I have changed the button to a split button (otherwise the href has no use at all, because it would be overwritten by the toggle).

Comment: That's a good answer but could you please change my [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjagZR) because I can't get it to work for some mysterious reason.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a few ways to do this, depends on what are you doing. 
Here's one example, if you have every action in scope in separate file, you can do something similar to this:

```
<form name="dropdownctrl>
<select name="list" accesskey="target">
<option selected>Whatever</option>
<option value="action.html">Action</option>
<option value="anotheraction.html">Another Action</option>
<option value="something else.html">something else</option>
<select>
<input type=button value="Go" onclick="goToNewPage(document.dropdown.list)">
```